# How to fill in another field with a foreignkey using django?

Tags: python, django

How can I get the related data from my `foreignkey`? When filling out my form, I have a model:

```py
class Service (models.Model): branch = models.ForeignKey (Endpoint, verbose_name = "Branch", on_delete = models.CASCADE)

pr = models.CharField (max_length = 50, null = True, blank = True, verbose_name = "test")
```

When selecting the relation that brings `branch`, I want to fill in the other field `pr` and put the other data that brings that relation of `branch`.

Comment: Please post this on [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com) or translate to English.

Comment: How can I get the related data from my foreignkey and when filling my form, I have my model

class Service (models.Model): branch = models.ForeignKey (Endpoint, verbose_name = "Branch", on_delete = models.CASCADE)

pr = models.CharField (max_length = 50, null = True, blank = True, verbose_name = "test")

what I want is that when selecting the relation that brings "branch", I fill in the other field in this case "pr" put the other data that brings that relation of "branch".

Comment: Don't forget to translate the title too